# does not show Google Maps in smartphone and not connection with webservice with ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to develop a mobile application with **Ionic framework**. It works in the web application, but when it is installed in smartphone, it does not work any more.

code **index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" >

    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="lib/ngstorage/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAXp19GmxccWT5A5vVgtQK5NHCaZDb_W0I">


    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="phonegp">

  <div class="tabs tabs-icon-top">
    <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="actualite">
      <i class="icon ion-document-text"></i>
      Actualité
    </a>
    <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="contact">
      <i class="icon ion-star"></i>
      Contact
    </a>
    <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="geo">
      <i class="icon ion-location"></i>
      Géo Localisation
    </a>
    <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="config">
      <i class="icon ion-gear-b"></i>
      Settings
    </a>
  </div>

  <ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-nav-bar class="bar-energized">
        <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
        <ion-nav-buttons>
          <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon ion-navicon"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
      </ion-nav-bar>

      <ion-nav-view>


      </ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
      <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="actualite">Actualite</ion-item>
      <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="contact">Contact</ion-item>
      <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="geo">Géo Localisation</ion-item>
      <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="config">Settings</ion-item>
    </ion-side-menu>
  </ion-side-menus>


  </body>
</html>
```

code **app.js**

```
// Ionic Starter App

  // angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
  // 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
  // the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
  app = angular.module('phonegp', ['ionic','ngCordova','ngStorage'])

  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

        // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
        // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
        // a much nicer keyboard experience.
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
      }
      if(window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });
  })

  app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
      $stateProvider.state("actualite",{
        url : "/actualite",
        templateUrl : "templates/actualite.html",
        controller:"getactualites"
      });

    $stateProvider.state("infoActualite",{
      url : "/infoAlite",
      templateUrl : "templates/infoActualite.html",
      controller:"infoActualiteCtrl"
    });

    $stateProvider.state("contact",{
      url : "/contact",
      templateUrl : "templates/contact.html"
    });

    $stateProvider.state("geo",{
      url : "/geo",
      templateUrl : "templates/geo.html",
      controller:"GeoCtrl"
    });

    $stateProvider.state("config",{
      url : "/config",
      templateUrl : "templates/config.html"
    });

    //pour afficher page index
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("actualite");

  })

  app.factory("StorageService",function($localStorage){
    $localStorage = $localStorage.$default({
      trajet: []

    });
    return {
      savePosition:function(pos) {
        $localStorage.trajet.push(pos);
      },
      getAllPositions:function(){
        return $localStorage.trajet;
      }
    }
  });

  app.controller("getactualites",function($scope,$http,$stateParams){
    $http.get('http://192.168.1.4/pfe/web/app_dev.php/api/users')
      .then(function successCallback( response ) {
        $scope.data = response;

      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);

        alert('error');
      })

  });

  app.controller("infoActualiteCtrl",function($scope,$http){


  });

        app.controller("GeoCtrl",function($scope,$cordovaGeolocation,StorageService){
          var counter;
          var currentLatitude;
          var currentLongitude;
          var markers = [];
          var options = {
            timeout:10000,
            enableHighAccuracy:true
          };
        $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options)
          .then(function(position){
            currentLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
            currentLongitude = position.longitude;

          $scope.position = position;

              var latLng= new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
              var mapOptions = {
                center: latLng,
                zoom: 16,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };
              theMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);
              $scope.map=theMap;
            $scope.newMarker(position,theMap);
            $scope.watchPosition(theMap);
            },
          function(err) { console.log(err); }
          );

          $scope.watchPosition=function(theMap){
            var watchOptions = {
              timeout: 2000,
              enableHighAccuracy: true
            };
            watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);
            watch.then(
              null,
              function(err) {
                //console.log(err);
              },
              function(position){
                //console.log(position);
                if ((position.coords.longitude!=currentLongitude) &&
                  (position.coords.latitude!=currentLatitude)){
                  $scope.position = position;
                  $scope.newMarker(position,theMap);
                }
              }

            );

          }

          $scope.newMarker=function(position,theMap){
            latLng= new google.maps.LatLng(
              position.coords.latitude,
              position.coords.longitude
            );
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position:latLng,
              title: "Position"+(++counter),
              label: "H"

            });
            marker.setMap(theMap);
            markers.push(marker);
            StorageService.savePosition({
              lat:position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            });
          }

          $scope.showMarker=function(p){
            latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position:latLng,
              label: "H"
            });
            marker.setMap($scope.map);
            markers.push(marker);
          }

          $scope.hideMarkers=function(){
            markers.forEach(function(m){
              m.setMap(null);
            })
          }

          $scope.showTrajet= function () {
            traj =StorageService.getAllPositions();
            traj.forEach(function(p){
                $scope.showMarker(p);
            });
          }

        });
```

code **style.css**

```
  .contact h5 {
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#444;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 8px;

  }
  .image img {
    margin:30px 0 0 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    padding: 10px;

  }

  .scroll {
    height: 100%;
  }

  #map {
    width:100%; height: 100%;
  }

  .icon {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .icon img {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
```

this is screenshot of problemes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqjKu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is yout plugins folder in your app's root/main (Same directory as WWW) if not

keep **plugins** folder in your app's **Root** directory then create platform with

```
ionic platform add android
```

and later app with

```
ionic build android
```

try this out

note: replace android with ios in above commands according to your requirement